# Calling a method and throws exception saying i'm passing in too many values... but i'm not

Tags: .net, vb.net

A bit of a strange question.

i'm calling a method and passing in 13 paramaters. when i run the code it throws and exception saying:

"13 arguments were passed to 'Lib.class::UpdateInformation'. 12 arguments were expected by this method."

I thought this was strange so i went to the method definition (through the right click menu in Visual Studio) and counted the number of parameters it was expecting and i counted 13.

Now i have either lost the ability to count overnight or there is something odd going on. any ideas on whats going worng here?

Additional info: There are no overloads for this method

Comment: Sanity check - post the call and method definition in your question.

Comment: Mattis, in the absence of more detail I doubt anyone can help you. What is this Lib.Class::UpdateInformation that you are trying to call and where did it come from? Normally we would search for details, but "lib", "class" and "UpdateInformation" are so ridiculously generic there will be a million hits.

Comment: They are custom built libraries and classes so you wouldn't find them anyway. unfortunately i had to be vague and replace the actual names due to my contract stating i cannot post code owned by the company on the internet (for security reasons apparetly).

Comment: I did however find the solution. Our test server had been rolled back to a previous version (i have no idea why) which had incorrect code on it for what i was trying to do which was causing the problem. The call to the server (written within that vague UpdateInformatation method) had originally been written without a trycatch block which was why the exception was being thrown a level higher that it should have been, causing the confusion.... Thanks for your attempts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types of one or more of the values you are passing are probably causing a match to the wrong method signature. Breakpoint it and examine the actual types of the values passed, first to last, and then look at the various method overload signatures. You will almost certainly find a match for an overload that takes fewer parameters than the one you intended to call.

Assuming you haven't accidentally passed parameters in the wrong order, you could coerce your values to the intended types which should force the match you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter... this was my first thought (i should have probably have added it to my question as well) but there are no overloads and it's taking 13 strings so nothing complicated in that respect.